# Wix - schedule custom action between StopServices and StartServices

Tags: wix, windows-services, custom-action

I would like to add a custom action in my Wix installer that runs between the StopServices and the StartServices. So that the service is down when the custom action is running. If I do the following the action runs before the StartServices, but also before the StopServices.

`<Custom Action="IisRewriteRules" After="StopServices" Before="StartServices"> NOT REMOVE~="ALL" </Custom>`

It seems that I can't add both a Before and After tag, that gives following error:

`Error CNDL0035: The Custom/@After attribute cannot be specified when attribute Before is present. (20)`

Is there some way I can achieve this? As a backup I guess I could stop the service in my custom action and restart it again at the end of the custom action, but I would prefer to not have to do that.

Looking online I couldn't really find anything. Is there maybe a way to schedule the ServiceControl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found in the [Wix Docs](https://wixtoolset.org/docs/v3/xsd/wix/custom/) that you can add a `Sequence` tag instead of `Before` or `After`. You can pass this an integer value and schedule it between the default actions. Following page shows the default actions and their corresponding `Sequence` value: [Suggested InstallExecuteSequence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/suggested-installexecutesequence)